# HP deskjet 1515 all in one printer not detecting by hplip toolbox

Tags: printing, hplip

I started using ubuntu before 2 months only. My printer is HP Deskjet ink advantage 1515 all in one printer. I have already installed HPLIP. I connected the printer through usb port. But the HP device manager not detecting the device. Some body please help me.

```
eleena@eleena-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install hplip
[sudo] password for eleena: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-gconf-2.0 appmenu-gtk linux-headers-2.6.32-21 nvidia-settings
  python-lxml appmenu-qt linux-headers-2.6.32-21-generic dkms cups-pk-helper
  libvdpau1 appmenu-gtk3 gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  printer-driver-postscript-hp
Suggested packages:
  hplip-gui system-config-printer
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  hplip printer-driver-postscript-hp
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 861 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,565 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main hplip i386 3.12.2-1ubuntu3.4 [85.1 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe printer-driver-postscript-hp all 3.12.2-1ubuntu3.4 [776 kB]
Fetched 861 kB in 28s (30.2 kB/s)                                              
Selecting previously unselected package hplip.
(Reading database ... 235335 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking hplip (from .../hplip_3.12.2-1ubuntu3.4_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-postscript-hp.
Unpacking printer-driver-postscript-hp (from .../printer-driver-postscript-hp_3.12.2-1ubuntu3.4_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for cups ...
Setting up hplip (3.12.2-1ubuntu3.4) ...
Creating/updating hplip user account...
Setting up printer-driver-postscript-hp (3.12.2-1ubuntu3.4) ...
eleena@eleena-desktop:~$ hp-setup

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.12.2)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-9 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Got bus address:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-1BiiSulszn,guid=98e2b27cef3913f43b51c2430000002d" 
Connected to accessibility bus at:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-1BiiSulszn,guid=98e2b27cef3913f43b51c2430000002d" 
Registered DEC:  true 
Registered event listener change listener:  true 
Searching... (bus=usb, search=(None), desc=0)
error: No devices found on bus: usb
```

Comment: Please refer to link for step by step procedure:-- http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/02/hp-linux-imaging-and-printer-hplip-version-3-13-2-releasedadds-support-for-more-printers/